# "You need administrator permission to make changes to this file", without actually making changes to the file

Tags: windows-7, permissions

It is the standard "You need administrator permission to make changes to this file" error about files on the C: drive.

Here comes the fun part:

1. I am an administrator

2. I have disabled UAC

3. I have disabled Admin Approval mode

4. I am the owner of the entire C: drive and all its subfolders and files

5. I have full control (read/write permissions on all)

But, wait... there's more!

I am not actually making changes to any files, this prompt pops up when I am **copying** files from the C: drive to a USB. And it happens for *.tmp files and some long-ass named system files, like volume information types of something.

Comment: Technically, you are making changes because if you copy to a another drive file permissions are changed.

Comment: @NoshadChaudhry, interesting, I thought that copying is just reading the source file. I just read an MSDN article about handling permissions, when copying but it did not say anything about changing the permissions, could you elaborate or point me in the direction of an article?

Comment: Without knowing the exact files, it's impossible to answer this question.

Answer (score 0):

I just meant it as an idea/ concept, which really more appropriately applies for moving files and the fact that you can't copy Permissions when you use copy.exe. I'm not implying that your changing the source files. I was just trying to point you in the right direction as far as thinking of reasons why it may be happening.

The root of the C drive is treated differently then most other areas of the computer as far as permissions. You can take control of it but in the end who really own it? The system and not you and this applies moreso if you take actions on system files. For example if you run an update or some MS fix or even a third party App your permissions can be removed.

You should expect to get this prompt when copying system files and operating in Non user folders.

If I find a good article I'll post it. Sorry, I deleted the article reference.

Comment: I am confused. As far as I know and from what I read - copying files does not change the source file's permissions, in addition Kmort's comment has little relevance, not only because it is about Linux, but because his conundrum is about changing a file, in use by another process. The message about being unable to access a file, because it is in use by another process is different, but thank you, anyway!